# update text widget from text field widget when textfield value is changed from various widgets

Tags: flutter

How to update the text widget with change in textfield. I want the text to change text where  ever there is a change in textfield either due to user input or due to button updating textfield.

I have used onChange but it only updated text widget on user put change but not on button click. I do not want on button click to updated text widget. In my actual scenario there can  be multiple events that can updated text field. So only on text field change I want text widget to update.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  String _helloText = 'Hello 0';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Number Incrementer'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              _helloText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (value) {
                // Update the "Hello" text whenever the value in the TextField changes
                setState(() {
                  _helloText = 'Hello $value';
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // On button click, increment the number in the TextField
                setState(() {
                  int currentValue = int.tryParse(_controller.text) ?? 0;
                  currentValue++;
                  _controller.text = currentValue.toString();
                });
              },
              child: Text('Increment'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Number Incrementer'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            /// Here, wrap your TextWidget with  ///ValueListenableBuilder<TextController>.
            ///It's automatically rebuild when change the TextEditingValue linked TextEditingController
            ///
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: _controller,
              builder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingValue value, Widget? child) {
                return Text(
                  ///
                  /// "Hello it's a constant text"
                  /// Just value changes when you change the TextEditingController
                  /// 
                  "Hello ${value.text}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                );
              },
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  int currentValue = (int.tryParse(_controller.text) ?? 0) + 1;

                  _controller.text = currentValue.toString();
                  _controller.notifyListeners();
              },
              child: Text('Increment'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if could add some text about changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to a controller in initstate(). This will update the widget using setstate() whenever textfield is updated or detect changes.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
 String _helloText = 'Hello 0';

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _controller.addListener(_updateHelloText);
 }

 void _updateHelloText() {
   setState(() {
     _helloText = 'Hello ${_controller.text}';
   });
 }

@override
void dispose() {
 _controller.removeListener(_updateHelloText);
 _controller.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}
```